# .Net Core ValidateAntiForgeryToken throwing web api 400 error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, antiforgerytoken

Visual Studio 2017 with Web Api using .net Core 1.1 I'm using, but I am getting a 400 Bad Request Error.

Error Occurs in every way:

1. Angular http
2. Fiddler
3. Postman
4. SoapUI
5. Swagger

ASP.NET Web API “400 Bad Request” on POST Request

```
[HttpPut]
//[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Put([FromBody]VeteranInteraction sessionTracker)
{ //.... }
```

Why is this happening ?

`ValidateAntiForgeryToken`  is the problem ,   if I comment it out it works.

Comment: have you tried removing `FromBody`? also post the exact data you are sending across from one of the sources (preferably from postman since that is the best for tests)

Comment: by the way 400 means the data you are sending is not in the expected format.

Comment: except that the json data sent worked when simply commenting out that token ...

Comment: Was this ever solved?

Comment: @paultechguy did it work for you? I have the same problem. I even hardcoded the token to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send the AntiForgery token on every request where it's being validated either as a cookie or as a http header.

Refer to the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery). They have a [section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery#angularjs) on how to configure angular js to do it.

Comment: I applied the exact implementation and can't get it to [work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48038980/why-antiforgerytoken-validation-keeps-failing)

Comment: @json did it work for you? I have the same problem. I even hardcoded the token to be sure.

Answer (score 9):

You must send the AntiForgery token on every request

```
 var arr = { City: 'Tehran', Age: 25 };
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("SaveAccess", "Access")",
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(arr),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function (request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("RequestVerificationToken", $("[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val());
        },
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
```