# .net core antiforgery token two are present in cookies and failing in validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am getting two ant forgery token in my code which is creating the validation failed

Below are the two code I have written to generate the anti forgery request and add attribute tag for all the post request

In configure service function i have added this lines

```
 services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
            {
                options.HeaderName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN";
            });
```

In configure function

```
        if (path.Contains("api", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))

        {
            // The request token can be sent as a JavaScript-readable cookie, 
            // and Angular uses it by default.
            var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
            context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken,
                new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false });
        }
```

Note: the value in the token i have edited and both values are different

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: There are two anti-forgery tokens in the cookies. Throwing 400 bad request because of anti forget validation failed

Comment: Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48038980/why-antiforgerytoken-validation-keeps-failing).